# Using LM2577 boost converter to charge the 2S lithium ion battery with an input of 15W at 5V

Tags: boost, lithium-ion, lithium

I am trying to design a  Lithium ion battery charger that can charge a 2S battery. The input power will be 15W at 5V. I am thinking of using LM2577 boost converter to efficiently step the input  up to charge a 2S battery. http://www.hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__26910__Arduino_LM2577_DC_DC_Adjustable_Step_up_Power_Converter_Module.html

Is it possible to use LM2577 to get the desired voltage and current rating to charge the 2S battery pack?

Comment: So your plan is to boost the voltage up, then connect a charge controller IC, right? You are just looking at the boost part now?

Comment: If that is a Chinese module, and I think it is because I have an identical one, do not trust the stated efficiency value: in mine it was written up to 94%, I measured 55%. The result is a strong heating of the module (10x more! 45% dissipated vs 5%), poor performances, and so on. I got 1/10 of the stated current. They use poor inductors, fake LMxxxx chips, ... I would recomment going for "western" modules like (just an example) the ones from Pololu (I won't post the link to avoid advertisement in search engines).

Answer (score 1):

Yes: it is possible to use that device.  But I wouldn't use it myself in this application.

The problem with LM2577 is that the built-in switching transistor has a fairly high ON voltage (saturated).  The data sheet says that saturation voltage is typical 0.7V with a maximum of 0.9V @ 2 Amps.  That voltage drop is a significant percentage of your 5V input, leading to poor efficiency.

I'm sorry that I don't have a better part number to suggest right now.  But there is a plethora of modern boost converters that will work well in this application.

How much current do you need?  I just recalled that I've used the Microchip MCP1640 as a boost converter in a couple of projects.

Another question to ask:

Why are you charging from a 5V 15W source?  Where does that 5V come from?  The reason I ask is that I'm guessing that you are charging from a mains-supplied power supply (either AC mains or vehicle battery).  What is the input voltage to that power supply's regulator.

In other words, there may already be a higher input voltage available for you to use for the battery charging.

Comment: Hi Dwayne ..thanks for your reply. I need 2200mAh at 2S which is about 18wh by math to charge the Lithium ion battery.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a charge management IC that uses boost configuration to charge two cells. I looked at TI's website, and they have some. I am sure there are other vendors also. To me, it does not make sense to boost, then use a linear regulator, nor does it make sense to boost, then buck.

Comment: @DwayneReid I am not using either AC mains or Vehicle battery.. The 5V comes from a Wireless Charger https://gigaom.com/2014/12/08/freescale-is-bringing-turbo-wireless-power-with-a-15w-qi-charger/ .. That has to be boosted to charge Lithium Ion battery...